# How do I punctuate this correctly (HELP]

Tags: nouns, punctuation

This couple: Mr. and Mrs. Robin Elsman, qualified for a loan on the house at a local bank.

OR

This couple: Mr. and Mrs. Robin Elsman qualified for a loan on the house at a local bank.

OR

something else?

Comment: Why do you need a colon? You use a comma, not a colon there. "This couple, Mr. and Mrs. Robin Elsman, qualified for a loan on the house at a local bank.

Comment: Why mention that they are a couple, if they are 'Mr' and 'Mrs' and if they are applying for a joint financial loan ? No need.

Comment: @Kris A comma. Gotcha. Thanks, Kris. In this situation, would an em dash work if I'm not sure which punctuation mark to use?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This couple: Mr. and Mrs. Robin Elsman, qualified for a loan on the house at a local bank.

Since you are addressing the couple first, a pause after their names helps separate the two phrases.

Comment: That is ungrammatical and not how you use a colon.